# Bitcoin Casino Questions

Tags: legal, gaming

I am developing a bitcoin dice based game. I am located inside the US. Do i did a gaming license to operate. Is it completely legal if not?

Comment: StackExchange should not be used for legal advice. Please contact a lawyer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it is asking for legal advice. No sane lawyer would answer here and tell you to consider it legal advice. If somebody claimed to be a lawyer, you still wouldn't have a way to check the claim's validity. Please don't ask for legal advice here on topics that matter to your legal well-being – hire a lawyer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no set rulings about gambling with crypto-currencies. It's kind of a gray area for now.

Comment: You might consider expanding upon this answer with a bit more detail. To the best of my knowledge it does appear to be technically accurate, but we typically prefer that answers contain more information than this and either cite a source or explain the logic by which the answer was obtained. Without these details it's hard to tell a valid answer from a popular opinion.